# How do i store data in a service-based database?

Tags: c#, database, wpf

I am trying to store the username and password inside a table called 'User' which is inside a service-based database.

Below is code of what i have tried.

```
private void Btn_register_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Create the conection string and open the conn
                SqlConnection conne = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\\CUC-SRV-FS02\Studio-StuHome$\13mihailovs.m\Documents\IT_Unit4\IT_Unit4\ITUnit4.mdf;Integrated Security=True");


                //Open the connection string
                conne.Open();

                //Get all the values from the text boxes etc and pass them over to the DB
                string insertQuery = "insert into User(Username, Password) " +
                    "values(@Username, @Password)";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conne);

                //Get values from the controls such as the text boxes and pass them over to the DB
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txt_username.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txt_password.Text);

                //This actually executes the query with the given values above.
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //Dispose the connection string once the data has been passed over the DB
               conne.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception problem)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error has occured");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you run this? Do you get an error?

Comment: @AndreasHassing yup as you can see in in the catch statement the message box will pop up.

Comment: And what type does the exception have, what's its message? Try setting a breakpoint in the catch block

Comment: @Loris156 What you mean by breakpoint.

Comment: @toborm I can see you have a catch block, yes, but that does not imply that the issue you're having is caused by an exception being thrown.
Try to copy the exception message into your question with something like: `MessageBox.Show(problem.ToString());`

Comment: @AndreasHassing i was just trying that i'll try adding the error.

Answer (score 0):

currect way for insert into database in Ado.Net:

```
    private readonly SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial 
    Catalog=dbPhoneBook;Integrated Security=True");

public string Add(string user , string pass)
    {
        string result = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = _con;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_login(user,pass)values(@user,@pass)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
            if (_con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _con.Open();
            }
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            result = "Ok";
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            result = "NOk";

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Also check the following
Check out the web site https://www.connectionstrings.com/ link to the database.